# Checking roles for an item

Tags: sharepoint, roles, splistitem

How can I check if current user has roles for editing, creating an item in a list in Sequential Workflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if current user has permissions on item, folder, list or site use [DoesUserHavePermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.doesuserhavepermissions%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to implement onWorkflowActivated event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265727.aspx )

To get permission on item level for current user u need:

```
SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection usersRoles = mysplistitem.AllRolesForCurrentUser;
```

see below link for more info;
http://sharepointmalaya.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/validate-user-base-permissions-before.html